# AJAX call gets a "400 bad request" response from my REST API

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest

AJAX call gets a "400 bad request" response from my REST API.  Here is the JavaScript:

```
var client_id = 'xxxxxx';
var client_secret = 'yyyyyy';

var username = document.getElementById("inputUsername").value;
var password = document.getElementById("inputPassword").value;

var params = {
  client_id: client_id,
  client_secret: client_secret,
  grant_type: 'password',
  username: username,
  password: password
};

var successCallback = function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
  console.log('Success: ', textStatus);
};

var errorCallback = function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  console.log('Error: ', jqXHR.status, textStatus, errorThrown);
};

var completeCallback = function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
  console.log('Complete: ', textStatus);
};

$.ajax({
  traditional: true,
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/token',
  contentType: 'application/json',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: params,
  success: successCallback,
  error: errorCallback,
  complete: completeCallback
});
```

I also tried setting the data using the following, but I got the same response:

```
var data = jQuery.param(params);
```

...with the corresponding change to the ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
  ...
  data: data,
  ...
});
```

I want to achieve the same result as using a curl command:

```
curl -X POST "http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/token" -d "client_id=xxxxxx&client_secret=yyyyyy&grant_type=password&username=aaaaaaa&password=bbbbbb"
```

Comment: Open the developer tools in your browser. Look at the request you are actually making in the Network tab. Look at any error messages that are reported in the Options tab. Odds are that you are failing to handle the [preflight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests) on your server.

Comment: Thank you.  After reading about the preflight options in the content section of the ajax page in the jquery manual I was able to fix the problem.

Comment: It is worth noting that calling an OAuth based REST API from JavaScript is insecure.  So this is not a good approach even when it is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed the contentType parameter in the AJAX call and the problem went away:

```
$.ajax({
  traditional: true,
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/token',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: params,
  success: successCallback,
  error: errorCallback,
  complete: completeCallback
});
```